# Opening Google Map intent without unlocking the device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, lockscreen

I have an app that makes use of the following intent in order to display a set of places on Google Map and start direction based on user choice:

```
Intent intent =
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + Uri.encode("mykeyword") + "&z=14"));
        // force to use Google maps
intent.setClassName(
    "com.google.android.apps.maps",
    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
```

The intent is started as follows:

```
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps")));
}
```

The code is triggered by my app activity that is displayed on the lock screen (thanks to the `android:showOnLockScreen="true"` property). It means the device is locked when the intent is used.

Unfortunately, the intent requires the user to unlock the device in order to have access to the Google Map activity.

I am looking for a way to display the Activity associated with the intent without having the user to unlock his/her device.

The only solution I have for now is to reimplement what is done by the `com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity` in my own activity. Unfortunately, this is a lot of work just to mimic what is done with the existing Google Map intent (i.e. displaying places for a given keyword, offering a field to change the keyword, displaying suggestions list, detail view, and direction, etc. all with a good UX).

Any experiences or ideas with such a scenario are welcome.

Comment: Facing a similar issue. I've come to the same conclusion that embedding / re-implementing the target activity's functionality seems to be the only way forward. If a visual representation isn't necessary, I've found you can at least start navigation. Did you find another method?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not found another solution for now. What a shame Google Map is not setting the right flag in their manifest to allow displaying their main activity on the lock screen.

Answer (score -1):

What I got is that you want to use your app whether screen is lock or unlock like Google Map Navigation, right?

Comment: I am already able to use my app whether the screen is locked or not. The issue I have is with the Google Map intent that starts its own activity in a context that is by default not allowed to display on the lock screen.